# Touchpad tab is missing on Samsung ATIV Smart PC Pro

Tags: keyboard, mouse, touchpad, samsung, tablet

I have a tablet Samsung XE700T1C with bundled dock keyboard. Ubuntu detects this keyboard, but doesn't detect a touchpad on it.

Ubuntu version: 16.04

[image]

My touchpad works,but in a limited mouse mode (no scroll, etc.)

He're my `xinput` output:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen stylus                 id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Atmel Atmel maXTouch Digitizer            id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom ISDv4 EC Pen eraser                 id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ USB Keyboard+SmartPad                     id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-50AFL11C54N                     id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ WebCam SC-20HDM12347N                     id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB Keyboard+SmartPad                     id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

Is there a way I can fix that?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `xinput` terminal command.

Comment: Ubuntu does detect the touchpad. But it is not fully supported in linux.

Comment: @Pilot6 I know. But I ask if there are some additional drivers that can make it work.

Comment: I do not think there are any linux drivers available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. It seems to be a bug that is still not solved.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1332824